# Always got nil value from the function in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm using AFNetworking for some GET queries. But my function always returns nil value. Where I was wrong?

```
+ (NSString *)getRequestFromUrl:(NSString *)requestUrl {
    NSString * completeRequestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, requestUrl];
    __block NSString * results;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:completeRequestUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        results = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        results = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error"];
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", results);
    return results;
}
```

Thx! Artem.

Comment: The AFNetworking GET:parameters:success:failure: function is asynchronous. By the time your hit your return line the networking is not done. You need to have some other way of getting the data out of the function. At the moment it goes... Create results, start connection, process a bit of connection, return results, process a but more of the connection, the connection finished, set the results string based on the outcome of the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not seeing a result because the blocks that you pass in for `success` and `failure` run asynchronously; by the time your `NSLog` gets called, the web service won't have returned yet. If you move your `NSLog` inside of your success and failure blocks, you should see a result get output to your console.

Because of the asynchronous nature of these calls, you won't be able to simply return the value from your method. Instead, you may want to take your own block as a parameter, which you can then call when you have a result. For example:

```
+ (void)getRequestFromUrl:(NSString *)requestUrl withCompletion:((void (^)(NSString *result))completion 
{
    NSString * completeRequestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, requestUrl];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:completeRequestUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *results = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseObject];
        if (completion)
            completion(results);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSString *results = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error"];
        if (completion)
            completion(results);
    }];
}
```

You would then call your method like so:

```
[YourClass getRequestFromUrl:@"http://www.example.com" withCompletion:^(NSString *results){
    NSLog(@"Results: %@", results);
}
```

AFNetworking's sample project has an example of using a block parameter to return a value from your web service calls: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/Example/Classes/Models/Post.m

Comment: @Fogmeister you should have been writing your answer instead of doing a mini answer in a comment!

Comment: Man, another question is: What should I do if I want to return something (NSArray) from completion block? My method is: - (NSArray *) methodname { [MyClass getRequest ... { //Filling NSArray }];

Comment: I'm getting "expected a type" in method's signature while calling using above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)POST:(NSString *)URLString 
          parameters:(id)parameters
          constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
          progress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgress
          success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
          failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
{

 [_manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",API_HOST,URLString] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    block(formData);
 } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress1) {
    uploadProgress(uploadProgress1);
 } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    success(task,responseObject);
 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    failure(task,error);
}];
}
```

Comment: Really?) 2013 year